# Custom backorder text from a custom field in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to change the backorder text on products to a value from a custom field under woocommerce product page?

I want to have a predefined text "available in xx days"

xx = value from a custom field under product:
[image: Custom Field]

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by using following code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'custom_on_backorder_text', 10, 2 );
function custom_on_backorder_text( $availability, $product ) {
$backorder_text = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME', true );

if( $availability['class'] === 'available-on-backorder' && ! empty( $backorder_text ) )
    $availability['availability'] = $backorder_text;

return $availability;}
```